# How to consolidate two tabs with different headers into one pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, pivot-table, google-colaboratory

I have two tabs to consolidate, they look like this:

Tab1: Employee Course Reimbursement

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Name    Institute_Name    Course_Name    Cost
000001    John        A                 PM             $100
000001    John        B                 DS             $150
000002    Nancy       B                 PM             $130
```

Tab2: Employee Membership Reimbursement

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Name    Membership?    Amount_Requested    Amout_Approved
000001    John        T                 $150             $100
000001    John        T                 $100             $100
000003    Steven      T                 $200             $100
```

So I would like to combine the tabs like this:

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Name    Institute_Name    Course_Name    Cost     Membership?    Amount_Requested    Amout_Approved
000001    John        A                 PM             $100
000001    John        B                 DS             $150
000002    Nancy       B                 PM             $130
000001    John                                                      T                 $150             $100
000001    John                                                      T                 $100             $100
000003    Steven                                                    T                 $200             $100
```

And the pivot table would be like

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Name    Cost
000001    John        $450
000002    Nancy       $130
000003    Steven      $100
```

I don't know how to combine the tabs with different headers. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Sandy Do you know how to join Left?

Comment: @ombk Yes. We can do left join. But don't forget we might exclude employees who only appear in that membership right table.

Comment: @Sandy indeed my bad I didnt notice that all the employees are there. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, sum(Cost) as Cost
from (
  select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Cost
  from `project.dataset.table1`
  union all
  select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Amout_Approved
  from `project.dataset.table2`
)
group by Emp_ID, Emp_Name
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

To get the combined table - use below

```
#standardSQL
select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Institute_Name, Course_Name, Cost, null Membership, null Amount_Requested, null Amout_Approved
from `project.dataset.table1`
union all
select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, null, null, null, Membership, Amount_Requested, Amout_Approved
from `project.dataset.table2`
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to combine the two tabs and get the combined table I shared above?

Comment: isn't the "pivot table" the result you expected? I thought it is. please clarify

Comment: Yes. I could do the pivot table if I get that combined table. So I'd like to know if we can conduct Union to get that third table (the combined one).

Comment: but my answer does give you that "pivot table" so I am confused now what exactly expected final result

Comment: I'd like to get that third combined table. The pivot table will be easily got if we have that third table. Your queries do really make sence.

Comment: ok. see update in my answer for combined table - even though I recommend getting final result w/o that combined table as it is much more efficient - but up to you